# Returns Data IF date range contains timestamp

Tags: node.js, express, date, mongoose

I'm using Nodejs, Express and mongoose what I'm Trying to do is the following.
I have this Object with the format:

```
{
  _id: 60c824cfeaaa84a7b4e16dbf,
  ActionID: 5f2715c9569c9700523bbcc3,
  ActionType: 'PushToBrand',
  EndDate: 2021-06-27T00:54:00.000Z,
  StartDate: 2021-06-15T00:54:00.000Z,
  ImageName: 'h21fTvVniZzqVAkY9oPJDj.jpg',
  ImagePlace: 1
},  
{
  _id: 60c824cfeaaa84a7b4e16sxf,
  ActionID: 5f2715c9569c9700523bbcc3,
  ActionType: 'PushToBrand',
  EndDate: 2021-05-27T00:54:00.000Z,
  StartDate: 2021-05-15T00:54:00.000Z,
  ImageName: 'h21fTvVniZzqVAkY9oPJDj.jpg',
  ImagePlace: 2
}
```

So, once the TimsStamp param is received, I need to filter the object that indeed contain the TimeStamp on the corresponding StartDate and EndDate range.

Maybe something like this:

```
BolBanners.find({StartDate: Is equal or greater than Date.now() && EndDate:_IS equal or minor than Date.now()});
```

***UPDATE

DB compas image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PajH4.jpg)

Comment: you can use `$lte` and `$gte` operators and use `new Date()` function.

Comment: I have tried this `const validImages = BolBanners.find({StartDate: {$lte: Date.now()}, EndDate: {$gte: Date.now()}}); ` and it didn't work.

Comment: see working [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JOKxqB83kks). use `new Date()`. and make sure field StartDate and EndDate both having date type not string.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'm getting clores, yet despite of the fact that StartDate and EndDate are date format, the query is nor running properly @turvishal

Comment: @turivishal thanks for you collaboration, unfortunately I'm missing something. This is my collection document [https://i.stack.imgur.com/PajH4.jpg] any other suggestion??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the Solution provided by @turivishal was correct. The fault was mine, due something I was ignoring and I didn't post it since I wasn't seeng the full picture.

I was querying like this:

```
var validImages;
try {
    validImages = BolBanners.find({
        StartDate: {
            $lte: new Date()
        },
        EndDate: {
            $gte: new Date()
        }
    });
    console.log(validImages)
    res.send(validImages);
} catch (e) {
    console.log('error')
    res.json({msg: 'no response'})
}});
```

But I was Missing the famous await, since it it an async function when you call your DB.

Thanks for the guidance.